# indexeddb (await async) Needed without .then()

Tags: ios, cordova, async-await, local-storage, indexeddb

when i try to change a cordova app from using to indexeddb
I create similar function for localStorage
Failed to set await async in the function below without then()!...
is it possible?

In the TESTING we have the first alert is not working(the result return now [object Promise])
and the second is working
I need a help to return a promise without .then()

thanks

````
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type = "text/javascript">
window.indexedDB=window.indexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB;
window.IDBTransaction=window.IDBTransaction || window.webkitIDBTransaction || window.msIDBTransaction;
window.IDBKeyRange=window.IDBKeyRange || window.webkitIDBKeyRange || window.msIDBKeyRange;   
if(!window.indexedDB){window.console.log("Your browser doesn't support a stable version of IndexedDB.");};
//----------
var db;
var Cnn=window.indexedDB.open("AP",1);
Cnn.onerror=function(event){console.log("error:");};
Cnn.onsuccess=function(event){db=Cnn.result;console.log("success:"+db);};
//----------
Cnn.onupgradeneeded=function(event){
    const BasicData=[
        {ID:"Colors",Val:"34495e|2980b9|98b4c7|d9e4e9"},
        {ID:"Lang",Val:"en~English|es~Español|fr~Française|de~Deutsch|tr~Türkçe|ar~العربية"},
        {ID:"L",Val:window.navigator.language.substring(0,2)}
    ];
    db=event.target.result;
    var objectStore=db.createObjectStore("BasicData",{keyPath:"ID"});
    for(var i in BasicData){objectStore.add(BasicData[i]);};
}
//----------
function idbFunc(ty,tb,ky,vl){//ty: HasKey,Get,GetAll,Set,Remove,RemoveAll
    let RW=(ty=='HasKey'||ty=='Get'||ty=='GetAll')?"readonly":"readwrite";
    let transaction=db.transaction([tb],RW);
    let objectStore=transaction.objectStore(tb);
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        if(ty=='HasKey'){
            let Cn=objectStore.get(ky);
            Cn.onerror=function(){console.log("Unable to read database!");reject(false);};
            Cn.onsuccess=function(){if(Cn.result){resolve(true);}else{resolve(false);}};
        }else if(ty=='Get'){
            let Cn=objectStore.get(ky);
            Cn.onerror=function(){console.log("Unable to read database!");reject(false);};
            Cn.onsuccess=function(){console.log("Get:"+Cn.result.Val);resolve(Cn.result.Val);};
        }else if(ty=='GetAll'){
            var r=[];
            objectStore.openCursor().onsuccess=function(event){
                let cursor=event.target.result;
                if(cursor){
                    r.push({ID:cursor.ID,Val:cursor.Val});
                    cursor.continue();
                }else{
                    resolve(r.length);
                };
            };
        }else if(ty=='Set'){
            let Cn=objectStore.add({ID:ky,Val:vl});
            Cn.onerror=function(){console.log("Unable to add!");reject(false);};
            Cn.onsuccess=function(){console.log("Added.");resolve(true);};
        }else if(ty=='Remove'){
            let Cn=objectStore.delete(ky);
            Cn.onerror=function(){console.log("Unable to add!");reject(false);};
            Cn.onsuccess=function(){console.log(K+" erased successfully");resolve(true);};
        }else if(ty=='RemoveAll'){
            var Cn=objectStore.clear();
            Cn.onerror=function(){console.log("Unable to add!");reject(false);};
            Cn.onsuccess=function(){console.log("Basic data has been erased successfully");resolve(true);};
        }
    })
}

// ------- TESTING -----------
setTimeout(function(){
    alert(idbFunc('Get',"BasicData",'Lang',''))
    idbFunc('Get',"BasicData",'Lang','').then(result =>{alert(result)})
},601);

</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>test</h1>
</body>
</html>
    ```
````